# Error thrown when approximating floating numbers in a list to scalar integers

Tags: python

I am trying to approximate the floating numbers in the list to scalar integer values. That is, i am trying to convert values lesser than 0.5 to 0 and values greater than or equal to 0.5 to 1. But i am getting error.

Values of my list looks like below:

```
0.2943,
0.3483,
0.3359,
0.3671,
0.6788,
1,
0.779
```

Expected output:

```
0,
0,
0,
0,
1,
1,
1
```

Code written:

```
listSample = []
listSample = list(y_predAN_PCA)

for i in listSample:
    if listSample[i] < 0.5:
        listSample[i] = 0
    else:
        listSample[i] = 1
```

But i got the below error:

**TypeError**: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `numpy` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over the items instead of the item indexes; use `enumerate` to get both:

```
listSample = list(y_predAN_PCA)

for i,s in enumerate(listSample):
    if s < 0.5:
        listSample[i] = 0
    else:
        listSample[i] = 1
```

Better still, use `round` and list comprehension:

```
listSample = [round(e) for e in listSample]
```

or, if you're using NumPy:

```
listSample = np.round(listSample)
```

Note: this will round 0.5 *down* to 0 ("Banker's rounding") and return a list of floats. Closer to your code (for positive numbers) would be:

```
listSample = [int(e+0.5) for e in listSample]
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got your answer by others. In case you have no issues using third party libraries, you can make use of masking with NumPy array. For such a small example case it would be an overkill but still it's good to know options.

**Explanation:** `lst<0.5` returns the array indices for which the value are less than 0.5. This is then passed as indices to the array `lst` as `lst[lst<0.5]` and those values are reassigned `0`. Similarly you check for values greater than equal to 0.5 and reassign them to 1.

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.array([0.2943,0.3483,0.3359,0.3671,0.6788,1,0.779])
lst[lst<0.5] = 0
lst[lst>=0.5] = 1
print (lst)
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
```

**Alternative better approach** as suggested by [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) is to use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Here, you first specify the condition (`lst<0.5` here). If the condition is `True`, the first value after the condition will be assigned to the array elements. If the condition is `False`, the second value will be assigned.

```
np.where(lst<0.5, 0, 1)
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: Nope... `np.where(lst < 0.5, 0, 1)` can compute the bitmask (or at least bulk it into chunks of what's to applied) and apply it vectorized to the resulting input in one go... While this approach requires a linear scan *twice* of the list to do the update...

Comment: @JonClements: I figured it out by playing around and from the docs.. Thanks a lot. I updated my answer

Comment: Also `np.round(lst)` might be valid here... depending on the rounding criteria and what should happen with values such as 2.7 or similar...

Comment: @JonClements: yes, that's the point. The OP didn't mention for values > 0.5, if there could be values such as 2.3, 5.4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using the for loop in the snippet in the code.In your code, *i* refers to the *i*th value in the list and not the *i*th index. The code below can help.

The range function will generate index as per the length of the list.

```
for i in range(len(listSample)):
    if listSample[i] < 0.5:
        listSample[i] = 0
    else:
        listSample[i] = 1
```